# Improve the Latency of my cycle in C#(.Net) application

Tags: c#, windows, embedded

I have a generic question regarding obtaining a ***very high latency***. I am coding for a target device which has **Windows Embedded Pro 7**. So i would assume that I can get real time performance (from what I have read). I am using "**System.Timers**" for setting a time cycle.Below is an example in

```
    public void updateCycle50ms( )
    {
        Stopwatch t = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        System.TimeSpan timer50ms = System.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);    
        while (1 == 1)
        {
            // Sending Message
            CANSEND(ref msg);  // This function sends Message over CAN network.  
            while (t.Elapsed < timer50ms)
            {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    }
```

What I try to do is send a message every **50 milliSecond**, but at the the cycle takes from **29ms to 90ms** (I can see it at receiving end). Can you guys tell me why I am not able to achieve my goal. Do I need to use another .Net class or there are special classes which can be used in **Windows Embedded** to get Real Time Performance (or closer to it).

Comment: I would use an event instead of a while loop to get better performance.  The answer to this question is very complicated.  There is a number of reasons you won't get a constant time.  F

Comment: Your code only *waits* for the first time, then `t.Elapsed < timer50ms` is always true, you need to restart the Stopwatch

Comment: I would use an event instead of a while loop to get better performance.  The answer to this question is very complicated.  There is a number of reasons you won't get a constant time.  First the TickTimer on the PC is processing the message like any other process and it depends on all the other processes running on the PC.  Second you are using TCP where transmission times depends on lots of factors.  Third TCP is reliable and the transmit end keeps a table of sent packets (max size ~1500 bytes)  so if a message is not acknowledged a retransmission will be sent.

Comment: What kind of event?, I am new in .Net as I have only written codes from ECU's and there is alwasys real time performance. @jdweng

Comment: I am not using TCP, I am using CAN protocol to send the message.

Comment: Serial Ports like CAN you should always use an event for receiving.  See following webpage for timer event : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [System.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) class:

```
private System.Timers.Timer timer;

public void updateCycle50ms( )
{
    // Create a timer with a 50ms interval.
    timer= new System.Timers.Timer(50);

    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
    timer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
    {
        // Sending Message
        CANSEND(ref msg);
    };

    // Have the timer fire repeated events (true is the default)
    timer.AutoReset = true;

    // Start the timer
    timer.Enabled = true;

    // If the timer is declared in a long-running method, use KeepAlive to prevent garbage collection
    // from occurring before the method ends. 
    // GC.KeepAlive(timer)
}
```

Comment: Hey @artem Mesha I tried ure method, less deviation but still not within limits.